headers[headerName].trim is not a function
Here is my code:
import { CopyObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
const s3Client = new S3Client({});

...

const params = {
   Bucket: "destination_bucket", // Destination bucket name
   Key: "abc.pdf", // Destination file name
   CopySource: {
      Bucket: "source_bucket", // Source bucket name
      Key: "xyz.pdf" // Source file name
   }
};
const command = new CopyObjectCommand(params);
const response = await s3Client.send(command);

When I run my code, I get bellow error. Although I have required permissions to both buckets.
TypeError: headers[headerName].trim is not a function
    at getCanonicalHeaders (/var/task/index.js:38660:62)
    at SignatureV4S3Express.signRequest (/var/task/index.js:38978:80)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


In the AWS SDK v3 for JavaScript, the CopySource field must be a single string in the format "/{sourceBucket}/{sourceKey}" rather than an object.
Here is the correct code:
import { CopyObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
const s3Client = new S3Client({});

...

const params = {
   Bucket: "destination_bucket", // Destination bucket name
   Key: "abc.pdf", // Destination file name
   CopySource: `source_bucket/xyz.pdf`, //Source bucket and Source file name
};
const command = new CopyObjectCommand(params);
const response = await s3Client.send(command);

